# Stopping Compiler from generating errors in a C++ code that has legacy C code

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors

I am porting a legacy C program to C++. However, the compiler is not happy and requires additional typecastings for C++. For example, I have this function...

```
 void foreach_element_in_patch(Patch *patch, void (*func)(), 
long arg1, long process_id);
```

In the original C Code, it is used like this...

```
 foreach_element_in_patch( patch, display_interactions_in_element, 
mode, process_id );
```

However, for C++ I need to typecast the second argument to stop the compiler from gernerating an error.

```
 foreach_element_in_patch( patch, (void (*)())display_interactions_in_element, 
mode, process_id );
```

The error generated by the compiler is the following...

```
invalid conversion from ‘void (*)(Patch*, long int, long int)’ to ‘void (*)()’
```

Now is there a way to ask the compiler not to generate errors for such things. I have tried prefixing this function with `extern "C"` but still the C++ compiler is not happy. My applications is loaded with such code and I do not have the time to adjust so much code.

Comment: The compiler is giving you errors for a reason, because it finds those conversions Unsafe, Why would you want to ignore them?

Comment: What's the signature of `display_interactions_in_element`? In general, compiler doesn't complain about function pointers without a reason.

Comment: If you are having problems with an error, it is probably best to tell us what the error is.

Comment: But it works fine in the original C code which is a benchmark application. I can safely ignore this error. How can I ask the C++ compiler to ignore it? I have tried prefixing the function with extern "C" but still the C++ compiler is not happy!

Comment: It works in C, because C is a different language. Would you like a Java or Haskell compiler to ignore the language differences too? You might as well ask a Python interpreter to run the code. It is C, not C++. In order for a C++ compiler to accept it, you need to rewite it as well-formed C++.

Comment: The compiler in C++ won't ignore it because it **is not a C compiler** and doing what you are doing is **unsafe**.  So either change it or go back to your C compiler

Comment: Heck, depending on what it's doing it might not be particularly safe C either.  It's passing an function with arguments to something that expects no function arguments.  If `foreach_element_in_patch` then calls that function without casting back to the correct number of arguments, the function will be called with its argument list uninitialized.

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to get Ruby to stop giving errors for the Perl code I pasted into my source?

Comment: OK enough of negative votings! Now can someone tell me of a tool that can do this for me, that is convert the C code to a valid C++ code?

Comment: @MetallicPriest: Nope. I've never heard of such a tool. The thing about languages is that converting between them correctly is *hard*. That's true for programming languages as well as human languages.

Comment: This wasn't even great C to begin with - nothing would have stopped you from providing the correct signature in the C code.

Comment: Just fix your C code to start with. Having a function pointer argument that hasn't a prototype is really hacky.

Comment: @Dave S, no in C this has a different meaning, see my answer.

Comment: I am very afraid. The real pathway for porting "legacy" C code to something different would be to first hoist it to c89/ANSI standards: fix the prototyping, take a look at the typing and sizes, etc. Also, you got to get to know the code: what kind of idiom does it use: casts, struct hack, pointer tricks, preprocessor magic, ... But putting a C++ kid on such a project is a recipe for disaster, IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to change the function prototypes and headers to declare the correct type of function pointer. So for example, for

```
void foreach_element_in_patch(Patch *patch, void (*func)(), 
 long arg1, long process_id);
```

I just need to change it to

```
void foreach_element_in_patch(Patch *patch, void (*)(Patch*, long int, long int), 
 long arg1, long process_id);
```

Instead of making changes at every function call.

Answer (score 6):

The error is quite clear, and your cast is invalid. You can't use a function that takes arguments as a function that doesn't take arguments.

For your code to work, you need to either:

1. Create a new function that calls `display_interactions_in_element` with sensible defaults.
2. Or use a capture-less and argument-less lambda that does the same (it might not be supported by your compiler, yet, though).

Note that if your code tries to call that function as if it took arguments later, it means the code is fundamentally broken.

Comment: @MetallicPriest: So what? C++ is not C.

Comment: Its not C, but it is supposed to be backward compatible with C, isnt't it? Aren't there any automated tools that can do it for me, it will take me ages to change this :(!

Comment: @MetallicPriest: Only to a certain extent. It is a common misconception that C++ is a strict superset of C. It isn't.

Comment: It is supposed to be *as backward compatible as possible*, while still being a better, stricter, more type safe language. Because C's type system is so broken, C++ had to break compatibility in a few ways.

Comment: Why do you need to change this, though? Why can't you just compile the code as C?

Comment: Because I need to insert some code which is written in C++, and I need to insert it right into the functions which are there in the C files. I can't put them in separate files that is.

Comment: @MetallicPriest: define the new code in a separate C++ file as an `extern "C"` function, then call it from within the C function that you need to modify? That's probably the closest you're going to get.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is a way. Compile your code as C.

C++ has stricter type safety rules, and requires you to explicitly cast types that could be implicitly converted in C.

So either compile the code as C, or make the modifications necessary for the code to be valid C++, and compile it as C++.

You should be able to compile your C files as C, your C++ files as C++, and then link them together without a problem.

But when you try to compile your C files as C++, the compiler is going to tell you if your code isn't valid C++.

Answer (score 3):

I think your error comes from the fact that the function signature is has a different meaning in C and C++. The second parameter specification

```
void (*func)()
```

in C means "a function with an unknown number and type of parameters" and in C++ it means "a function without arguments". So these are quite different and it **must** crash.

The error is not in the lack of type safety of C, but in your code. Don't do that. Use strict prototypes, even in C. The correct parameter specification for both languages is just

`void (*func)(Patch*, long int, long int)`

that's it and everything is just blindly hacking around.